# How prove this linear algebra $|\alpha-\beta|\le|\alpha-\gamma|$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**

Let $V$ be a Euclidean space, and $U$ be a subspace of $V$. For $\beta\in U$, show that:

> $\beta$ is the orthogonal projection of $\alpha\in V$ on to $U$
>
> $\Longleftrightarrow \forall \gamma \in U$, we have $|\alpha-\beta|\le|\alpha-\gamma|$

This problem is from this PDF problem 4: http://wenku.baidu.com/view/1355593387c24028915fc3df.html

I post this pdf solution:

(1):$\Longrightarrow $

since
$\beta$ is the orthogonal projection of $\alpha\in V$ on to $U$,then there $\xi\in U^{\perp}$,such $\alpha=\beta+\xi,\forall \gamma\in U$.

since $\beta-\gamma\in U$,so
$$(\alpha-\beta,\beta-\gamma)=(\xi,\beta-\gamma)=0$$
so
$$|\alpha-\gamma|^2=|(\alpha-\beta)+(\beta-\gamma)|^2=|\alpha-\beta|^2+|\beta-\gamma|^2\ge|\alpha-\beta|^2$$
so
$$|\alpha-\beta|\le|\alpha-\gamma|$$

(2):$\Longleftarrow $

let $\gamma U$,have $$|\alpha-\beta|\le|\alpha-\gamma|$$,then follow it only prove this :
$\beta$ is the orthogonal projection of $\alpha\in V$ on to $U$

so  we  let other $\beta_{1}$ is the orthogonal projection of $\alpha\in V$ on to $U$, then we use $(1)$ reslut we have
$$ |\alpha-\beta_{1}|\le|\alpha-\beta|\le|\alpha-\beta_{1}|$$

so
$$|\alpha-\beta|=|\alpha-\beta_{1}|$$,
note $\alpha-\beta_{1}\in U^{\perp},\beta_{1}-\beta\in U$, then we have
$$|\alpha-\beta|^2=|(\alpha-\beta_{1})+(\beta_{1}-\beta)|^2=|\alpha-\beta_{1}|^2+|\beta_{1}-\beta|^2$$
so
$$|\beta_{1}-\beta|=0\Longrightarrow \beta=\beta_{1}$$

**OH,Now I know this solution why not true. when prove $(2)$,this $\beta_{1}$ maybe can't exsit.**

**so this solution is not true,and How prove it?**

**By the way:**  my teacher tells me this solution is not true? why? then how do we prove this problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Sketch: If $P$ is the orthogonal projection then 
$$|\alpha-\gamma|^2=|\alpha-\beta+\beta-\gamma|^2=|\alpha-\beta|^2+|\beta-\gamma|^2$$
because $\alpha-\beta$ and $\beta-\gamma$ are orthogonal.

Comment: then follow is true?Thank you,can you say why this link solution is not true?

Comment: @chinamath: The proof you posted seems perfectly fine to me. did you ask your teacher why he thinks the solution is wrong?

Comment: My teacher tell me consider byself

Comment: Oh,I know my post this solution when prove $\Longleftarrow $ this $\beta_{1}$ maybe can't exsit?

Comment: @chinamath: Of course $\beta_1$ exists (if your vector spaces are finite dimensional). You are supposed to prove an equivalent definition of the orthogonal projection. So you should inform yourself about how to define the orthogonal projection onto a subspace of $V$ in the first place!